# Sharepoint can not save background-image style in multiple lines of text column?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I created a custom list, after that I created a column "multiple lines of text" with "Enhanced rich text". After that, I created a new item, and I input html source to that column.

For example:

```
<div class="hdg-container" style="background-image: url(img/home-background-1.jpg) ">
```

Note: I do not want to use an external style sheet.

I saved that item, when I open it the background-image style was removed. Please help me.

Comment: did you try adding 'background-size:cover' as well?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the background image of the new or edit form, you would choose the wrong way. you can do it with the SharePoint Designer tool.